# Sphinz Zone failing

Tags: html, sphinx

As far as I can tell I set up zones correctly in my index:

- html_strip = 1
- index_zones = title

and queried correctly

```
select  ID, Title from idx_Table WHERE (MATCH('zone:(title) "ABC"'))
```

and naturally have a test record:

```
<title>Bla bla- ABC XYZ</title><description>Yada yada yada</description>
```

Yet the query fails to return results such as

```
<title>Bla bla ABC</title>.
```

I can't find any other index settings I could be missing, any thoughts from Sphinxperts?

Comment: What means 'fails'? Thats not a very descriptive description of the problem. What exactly doesnt work???

Comment: @Barryhunter Fails to return the test record indicated, I updated the question in case any one else had the same confusion.

Answer (score 0):

SphinxQL is picky: "zone" needs to be "ZONE".

Comment: Ah, well to be picky ZONE is a extended query operator. Its not part of SphinxQL. To SphinxQL, the text query is a opaque string.

Comment: @barryhunter If you mean that SphinxQL won't recognize it it is in fact recognizing it when I use ZONE in my query.